# Reconnect to TCP/IP socket on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

I use "net" library to create TCP connection on my nodeJs.

```
root.socket = net.createConnection(root.config.port, root.config.server);
```

I'm trying to handle error when remote server is down and reconnect in Cycle.

```
root.socket.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('socket error ' + error);

        root.reconnectId = setInterval(function () {
            root.socket.destroy();
            try {
                console.log('trying to reconnect');
                root.socket = net.createConnection(root.config.port, root.config.server);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('ERROR trying to reconnect', err);
            }

        }, 200); 
}
```

The trouble is that in case of remote server shutdown I still get en error and my nodeJS server stops.

> events.js:72
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                 ^ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>       at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
>       at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)

Comment: and? what's your question?

Comment: sorry posted before the question was done

Comment: this error is raised even after adding the error listener?

Comment: Yes. I do see 'trying to reconnect' in log. And after that my server shut's down with an error. I don't see 'ERROR trying to reconnect' in log.

Comment: ah, I understood your problem, the error isn't caught because it happens in another cycle of the main loop and is outside of the "try / catch" statement, I'll post soon a solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
var net = require('net');

var c = createConnection(/* port, server */);

function createConnection(port, server) {
    c = net.createConnection(port, server);

    console.log('new connection');

    c.on('error', function (error) {

        console.log('error, trying again');

        c = createConnection(port, server);
    });

    return c;
}
```

In your case you are creating a new connection but you don't attach any error listener, the error is raised somewhere else in the execution loop and can not be caught by the "try / catch" statement.

P.S. try to avoid using "try / catch" statement, error handling in Node.JS is made using error listeners and domains, it can be useful only for `JSON.parse()` or other functions that are executed synchronously.